Is there any evil Devatas (other than Rahu and Ketu)?
We should know about there was also Good Asuras (like Prahlada, Vibhisana, etc). But,Is there any evil devatas other than Rahu and Ketu?

Saturn is the most malefic planet or Deva. The very incarnation of evil itself.

Isn't supposed to be only awarding people's karma?

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Is Saturn not linked with instilling discipline? I mean I do see many people praying to Saturn generally (even though they may not be having sadsati)...so could you kindly elaborate? (I am new to astrology so I am learning)

@Adhway Good question. Traditional astrology texts, even Puranas say it categorically that it is evil. However, modern texts try to sugarcoat it, especially western texts.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Ohh, I get it now. Thanks...

@Adhway people pray to Saturn out of fear, not out of devotion! They are so scared that they try to appease him! Though the effort is futile.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Oh... but that raises another query in my mind.. should a person not pray to saturn? Like even if hypothetically a person wants to pray with devotion to saturn, will it be wrong to do that?

@Adhway Nothing wrong. You can pray. But the point is Saturn won't buzz! It did not even spare its Perceptor! That bad is his reputation. It is called Graharaja, because it is most powerful. No other plant's influence can stop him from giving results. Nothing can stop Saturn!

@AmirtenduMukhopadhyay I think you should answer for this. Can you pls answer to this question?
